# Visual Studio 2015 Syntax Error Suggestions Stopped Appearing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, syntax-highlighting

Late last night I stopped receiving syntax error suggestions (the little light bulb icon) on mouseover. Even the hotkey "Ctrl +" is no longer working. I have tried resetting Visual Studio settings, Restarting Visual Studio and restarting my computer. I've come to use these a lot so I'd really like to have them displaying again.

Just to be clear, Syntax Error Suggestions are supposed to look like this:
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M33oo.png)

I am now getting this:
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZJTt.png)

When it would usually recommend I add "using System.Data.SQLite" at the top of the file. 
Thanks in advance!